# Put a href link into a Struts2 set tag

Tags: tags, struts2, escaping, struts

I want to put an anchor tag into a Struts2 variable that I can then display at various points in a JSP.  That way I can avoid duplicating the complicated if/then statements that are used to build various forms of the href tag.

I'm using the Struts 's:set' tag to do this.

The problem is that Struts converts the '<' characters to htmlentities and when the page displays I see the actual "a href=someURL"  tag displayed, not a working link.

If I add the "escape='true'" argument to s:set it does the same thing, only it displays the htmlentities for the '<' and '>' tags.

How do I put a valid anchor tag into a Struts2 variable and then display it as a working link?

Here's what I'm doing:

```
<s:set name="composerName">

<s:property value="'a href=%{viewRecordURL}>'" escape="false"/>

<s:property value="#composer.title" />

<s:property value="#composer.firstName" />

<s:property value="#composer.lastName" />

<s:property value="'</a>'" escape="false" />

</s:set>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `s:url` to create a valid url and then use it in `s:a` to generate the link.

You can refer the link below for more details:

http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8/docs/a.html

Comment: No good reason to use `<s:a>`, though, unless you're using it for an Ajax request.

Answer (score 2):

We can use url tag to create URL like mention below

```
<s:url id="hLink" action="yourStrutsActionName">
   <s:param name="propertyName" value="%{propertyName}" />
</s:url>
<td><s:a href="%{hLink}"><s:property value="%{propertyName}"/></s:a></td>
```

Comment: Attribute `id` is deprecated use `var` instead.

Answer (score 1):

do this easy way to set the link in Struts2
// add the Struts2 action in href

```
<s:a href="forgetPasswordPage.action" >Forget Password</s:a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't how you want to build this--what you have is two different things, a URL, and the text string of that url. The URL you already have. Only use `<s:set>` for the link text.

If you really need to, you can wrap this up into a JSP-based custom tag, but I wouldn't bother.

Comment: The problem is that I need to wrap both parts, 1) the URL - which is defined in an iterator (not shown) using s:url - and 2) the text string of the s:a tag into a Struts s:set variable so it can be used in various places in the page without recreating some logic (also not shown for brevity) that was used to create alternate version of the link.  But see my own answer to my question below.

Comment: @Ron Then I'd probably consider trying `<c:set>`. I don't really understand what you're doing, and I'm not yet convinced this is a good way to do it--this smacks of too much logic in the view so far.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question.  Maybe someone else has a more elegant solution.  Once again, we're trying to get both an anchor tag and a url into a s:set variable.  The issues were two:  1) getting s:set to treat the tag string as a literal string and not an Object (which it wants to fetch from ActionContext or somewhere), and 2) turning off escaping so that the string text of the anchor tag isn't converted into htmlentities like '& lt;'.

For 1, I set the var to null, but provide a default argument, which s:property always treats as a literal string.

For #2, it's just a matter of using escape="false" in the right places.

Unfortunately, the string has to be built up with separate bits of s:property, but what can you do?

```
<s:set name="composerName" >
    <s:property value="" default="<a href=" escape="false"/> 
    <s:property value="" default="'" />
    <s:property value="%{viewRecordURL}" escape="true"/>
    <s:property value="" default="'>" escape="false" />
    <s:property value="#composer.title" />
    <s:property value="#composer.firstName" />
    <s:property value="#composer.lastName" />
    <s:property value="" default="</a>" escape="false"/>
</s:set>
```

I haven't tested it yet with UTF-8 characters or potentially problematic characters like '&', apostrophe, or single quote in the #composer part.

Comment: Still ew. Too much work in the view; I don't understand the usecase for this.

Comment: What's happening is that this JSP is using the authz:authorize tag from Springframework, alongside Struts2.  A lot of what Struts is asked to do depends on conditional statements based on Spring.  So this JSP ends up being kind of an intermediary between the two.  There is a Struts bean defined, I could throw some of this ugly stuff up there, I suppose, to get it out of the JSP.

Comment: On second thought, there's a bunch of stuff using strings from external resource files, values from the Action class, and Spring.  Even if I pull this all together in a call to some utility bean to construct the link (and get rid of the ugly Struts code), the amount of code reduction in comparison to the whole is negligible.

Comment: Like all of it, except the URL; I just can't think of any possible tag/framework/whatever interaction that would force you to generate links like this. Doesn't mean it isn't possible, but... I sure don't see it.

Comment: Not in *that* snippet there isn't.

Comment: Oh, you mean just the ${viewRecordURL} part?  viewRecordURL comes from a s:bean, which in turn uses data pulled from the ActionContext (and is also within a Spring authz:authorize conditional statement, not that that matters).  I didn't write this code, there's an awful lot of logic here, but I can understand why they put it in the JSP since it's pulling together stuff from Spring, ActionContext, and resource files.  What about the viewRecordURL do you not like, if that's what you're referring to?

Comment: I'm really talking about the whole thing--I just don't get why it's like that. Whatever; without knowing more it's not worth going back and forth about :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I just solved it as following:

In the main bean, I have the following variables with Setters and Getters:

```
private int ReqNo;
private String hyperLinkToPage;
```

In the JSP page I have the TD as following:

```
    <td class="displayValue" style="width: 10%;"><s:a href="%{hyperLinkToPage}"><s:property value="%{ReqNo}"/></s:a></td>
```

I hope that it will help.